# Flutter: Where is the keystore file generated by keytool command?

Tags: flutter, keystore, keytool, jks

Base on flutter docs, the keystore should be located on the directory you provided on keytool command, but once you check the directory, there's none, where is it?

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ./keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec. 2022, it doesn't matter what directory you give on keytool command because it will always generate the keystore on the base root of flutter project.

[image]

But despite all that, it is still important to move it to somewhere safe or logical, in my case **android/app/**

Comment: Why is the `android/app` directory logical when you are also building the app for iOS, Linux, MacOs, Web and Windows?